# How To Bind Dynamic List from AngularJS to Html Table?

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a Angular Function

```
             vm.OpenBManageContractBillingReport = function () {
                 reportService.GetContractBillingList(vm.Search).then(function (response) {
                     console.log(response);
                vm.contractBillingReportList = response;
            }, function (err) {

            });
        };
```

which gives the output of the list from API and the dynamic list is stored in vm.contractBillingReportList. But the Output may be different According to Start Date and End Date Parameter in `vm.search`. For Ex:- IF start Date Parameter is `1/1/2018` and End Date Parameter is `31/1/2018` the Result Provides Only One Column January 2018. Similarly, IF start Date Parameter is `1/1/2018` and End Date Parameter is `31/12/2019` the Result Provides 24 Col from January 2018 to December 2019. How Can I bind this data with Header Column in HTML Table?

```
            <div class="clearfix">
           <div class="reportTable">
               <div class="col-sm-12" style="padding:0;">
                   <table class="table table-bordered">
                       <thead>
                           <tr></tr>
                       </thead>
                       <tbody>
                           <tr ng-repeat="item in vm.contractBillingReportListtrack by $index">
                               <td></td>

                           </tr>
                       </tbody>
                   </table>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming contractBillingReportList is an array of objects with keys of the object required as header. Just loop for keys in the first element and display those keys as headers.

```
<tr>
  <th ng-repeat="(header, value) in vm.contractBillingReportList[0]">{{header}}</th>
</tr>
```